# MySQL or PostgreSQL? Using Mathematica only I need to choose one

Tags: databases

Installing either MySQL or PostgreSQL. My concern is just with Mathematica. I am going to be using it to store a good bit of basic data but the main thing is fast image retrieval and comparison using Mathematica as the comparing engine. Anyone have experience with any of this? Thoughts, directions or more questions?

Comment: I use both, much prefer Postgres.The interfacing capabilities and datatype definition are pretty peerless. Probably better to ask this on their respective fora...

Disclaimer: Illustra (commercialized Postgres) was one of my startups.

Comment: I have only ever used MySQL so cannot comment on a database comparison but as far as interfacing with Mma goes it is nice and easy.

Comment: Might be a better question for the WCommunity, since this is a [subjective](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question.

Comment: @bobthechemist -- I don't think we can regard this as a subjective question.  MySQL and PostgeSQL have different capabilities and performance because of their inherent designs.  PostgreSQL has more institutional capable performance.  Head to head PostgreSQL provides a viable alternative to top tier database base platforms (including the likes of Oracle and SAP) in their core markets.  MySQL doesn't really do that. All of this said, the OP has a specific need.  Given that one can download both these platforms for free, why not simply test them?

Comment: @Jagra Fair enough. Perhaps additional details from the OP would be helpful.  Is the question "Is there a measurable difference in performance between the two database packages when retrieving <insert size> images via Mathematica?"

Comment: Im this case the image size is quite large by todays standards. I am trying for 12+ MegPxls. Any given access would have 30 or so Quaries (transfers) of such images. I am trying this at much lower resolution. The above numbers, an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). Very fast, super flexible (eg write your own functions and aggregate functions in java), administration is very convenient. I've had a lot of success using it in research to organize and store numerical data.